# Creating menu in wordpress and changing href manually from files

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the default main nav menu in Wordpress and i cant find it in php.. I want to change the links cause i dont have that option in dashboard.. Does anybody know where is it? Thanks in advance...

Im trying to find this one, so i can change "a href "

```
        <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1"    class="menu"><li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-  item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-  32"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/">Αρχική</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-44"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/%cf%80%cf%81%ce%bf%ce%b3%ce%bd%cf%89%cf%83%cf%84%ce%b9%ce%ba%ce%ac/">Προγνωστικά</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/bonbonitas/">Bonbonitas</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/%ce%b5%ce%b3%ce%b3%ce%bb%ce%ad%ce%b6%ce%bf%cf%82/">Εγγλέζος</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/ghostbet/">Ghostbet</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-46"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/stats/">Στατιστικά</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-39"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/%ce%b2%ce%b1%ce%b8%ce%bc%ce%bf%ce%bb%ce%bf%ce%b3%ce%af%ce%b5%cf%82/">Πρωταθλήματα</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/tziroi/">Τζίροι</a>         </li>
<li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/highlights/">Highlights</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
  <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/wins/">Επιτυχίες</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/%cf%80%cf%81%cf%89%cf%84%ce%bf%cf%83%ce%ad%ce%bb%ce%b9%ce%b4%ce%b1/">Πρωτοσέλιδα</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/%ce%b5%cf%84%ce%b1%ce%b9%cf%81%ce%af%ce%b5%cf%82/">Εταιρίες</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a href="http://bonbonita.16mb.com/contact/">Επικοινωνία</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure of what you've asked here. Since all is in php and you won't find these lines in your code. You should try using maybe an external url to your page.

Comment: Ok sorry for confusing text.. i want to change the url of my menu... But i dont have that choice... When i create a page it automatically link you to that.. I want to create a choice in menu and link to other site... I hope u understand what im askin for... Sorry for my bad english

Comment: As Dejo Dekic answered, you would have to add a "custom link" to your menu.

Comment: Can u plz let me know how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a "custom links" option inside your dashboard if you first create a menu.

Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TkXaoMIzQ4) to show you how it's done.

And here is [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) if you like reading.

You can also change links on your "posts" and "pages" option is located just below your "post" and "page" title (when you are adding content)

Comment: Thats my problem m8... I dont have that option.... i want in my menu to add Other button and link to other site...

Comment: Well as I was saying you need to create a menu first in order to have that option please see the links...

Comment: Thnak you so much guys

Comment: My mistake was that i made pages and not links... Thank you so much.. U saved my life